# CreateLink doesnt work in IE7/IE8 when overlapping text is selected

Tags: javascript, text-editor

Please refer to this link for a [rich text editor](http://www.mozilla.org/editor/midasdemo/)

It works great in Mozilla. The problem comes in IE.
This is the use case.

1) Add Some text
2) Add a link to some portion of the entered text.
3) Now select some more text overlapping the previously selected text and add a link.
4) In mozilla this works fine and the complete  tag is replaced with the new link
5) In IE somehow it doesnt work. It doesnt add the new link overwriting the previous link.

Can anyone help me in this.

Regards,
Tina Agrawal

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the demo there is not a cross browser implementation -- [although the code is very similar](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Firefox_:_Midas#How_is_it_similar_to_Internet_Explorer.27s_feature.3F__How_is_it_different.3F).

A more cross-browser implementation that you can try is available at http://www.kevinroth.com/rte/, although it's old and I noticed at least one bug right away.

I would much rather recommend TinyMCE to you.  It's fully cross browser compatible, easy to integrate and open source.  http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/